# PyCharm copy console indicator (`>>>`) when copying text from Python console

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, console, jetbrains-ide

When I copy this text:

[image]

and paste it into a text field, I just get:

```
scipy.special.softmax([1,1])
array([0.5, 0.5])
```

I would like to get:

```
>>> scipy.special.softmax([1,1])
array([0.5, 0.5])
```

This is the behaviour when using the Python interactive console normally outside PyCharm.

Answer (score 4):

this seems to be reported already, please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52621/Unable-to-copy-code-from-the-console-as-plain-text and feel free to vote in order to increase the priority.

I apologize for the inconvenience.